# Determining the locations of linked msaccess .accdb files from outside of access

Tags: winapi, ms-access, installation

I'm writing an updater for an msaccess based application that has several linked .accdb files that could be in various locations on the hard disk.  We need to replace older .accdb's with newer ones periodically, but won't necessarily know where they are since the customer can move them around.

Since the updater operates outside of the access code, I haven't found a good way to programatically determine the locations of all linked .accdb files given a front file.

Is the only way to do this from inside msaccess itself?  Or does anyone have a more clever way of determining the locations of these files?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since the user can move them around I would ask the user directly through a custom dialog. I don't see how you can find all of them dynamically.

Comment: Can you do this outside of Office? Just use Windows to search for the databases you want to replace? (This assumes you know their names in advance)

Comment: Will the accdb files always be on the local system or could they also reside on a network share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know

1. The linking accdb
2. The name of the linked tables (In sample they are foo and bar)

You can query the `MSysObjects` table via ODBC or OleDB e.g.

```
SELECT Database 
FROM msysobjects
WHERE 
     ForeignName in ("Foo", "Bar")
```

There might also exist an Automation approach but that will depend on what the updater  is written in.